# Fundamental matrix of $x'= (-1+\frac{3}{2}\cos^2t)x+(1-\frac{3}{2}\sin t\cos t)y,~y'=(-1-\frac{3}{2}\sin t \cos t)x+(-1+\frac{3}{2}\sin^2t) y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, fundamental-solution

> Find the fundamental matrix of the system of odes:

$$\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    x \\
    y\\
     \end{array}
\right]'=
\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    -1+\frac{3}{2}\cos^2t & 1-\frac{3}{2}\sin t\cos t \\
    -1-\frac{3}{2}\sin t \cos t & -1+\frac{3}{2}\sin^2t\\
\end{array}
\right]\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    x \\
    y\\
\end{array}
\right].$$

*Attempt.* The coefficient matrix is not constant, so we may not use the eigenvalue-eigenvector method. I wrote the system as:

$$x'= \left(-1+\frac{3}{2}\cos^2t\right)x+\left(1-\frac{3}{2}\sin t\cos t\right)y$$
$$y'=\left(-1-\frac{3}{2}\sin t \cos t\right)x+\left(-1+\frac{3}{2}\sin^2t\right) y$$

and since both have non-zero coefficients, maybe a combination of these two equations would lead us to a solvable form. I didn't end up to such a combination though. Another idea was to differentiate the first one and reach a second order linear ode for $x$ (but also led me to non-constant coefficients).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Of course. It is from an exam on Dynamical Systems.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, we may verify the solution. The method proposed before though is not applicable in our case ($A(t)$ is neither $a(t) M$, nor $a_1(t)M_1+a_2(t)M_2$).